# django rest JSONWebTokenAPIView serializer-class object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, jwt

i am extending JSONWebTokenAPIView from rest_framework_jwt to my custom view :

```
class UserLogin(JSONWebTokenAPIView):

     serializer_class = serializers.AdabaziUserLoginJWT
```

and here is my custom serializer class:

```
class AdabaziUserLoginJWT(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(style = {'input-type':'password'})
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='show_status')
    #token = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta():
        model = Adabazi_user
        fields = ('status')

    def show_status(self,obj):
        return obj.status

    def validate(self,attrs):

        credentials={
        'username' : attrs.get('username'),
        'password' : attrs.get('password')
        }

        user = authenticate(**credentials)
        if user :
            if user.is_active:
                ada_user = Adabazi_user.objects.get(user=user)
                if ada_user.status ==1:
                    ada_user.status = 2 #user is logged in right now
                    ada_user.updated_at = timezone.now()
                    user.last_login = timezone.now()
                    payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
                    token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
                    return {
                            'token':token,
                            'user':user,
                            'adabazi_user' : ada_user}
                else:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError('User is already logged in.')
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Account is deactivated.')
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User credentials failed.')

    def create(self,validated_data):
        user = validated_data['user']
        adabazi_user = validated_data['adabazi_user']
        user.save()
        ada_user.save()
        return ada_user
```

but when i want to `POST` `username` and `password` to `localhost/api/user/login/` which this url is connected to my view ; this error occured :

in this line of code `post` method of JSONWebTokenAPIView makes error
`user = serializer.object.get('user') or request.user`

```
Exception Value: 'AdabaziUserLoginJWT' object has no attribute 'object'
```

how can i access serializer instance object attribute ?
is there any object attribute for serializers at all?

Comment: I think your AdabaziUserLoginJWT should extend ModelSerializer

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the same error, and it seems like the issue is with the integration of the *rest_framework_jwt* library and the *rest_framework* itself: the *rest_framework_jwt* seemingly has not been updated with the newest version of *rest_framework*, while the code in *rest_framework*'s serializers changed (see [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.0-announcement/#serializers)).

In the new version of *rest_framework* there's no such syntax as `serializer.object.get`, because:

> Previously the serializers used a two-step object creation, as follows:
>
> Validating the data would create an object instance. This instance would be >available as serializer.object.
>      Calling serializer.save() would then save the object instance to the database.
>
> We now use single-step object creation, like so:
>
> Validating the data makes the cleaned data available as serializer.validated_data.
>     Calling serializer.save() then saves and returns the new object instance.

So, as a result, in order to use this class you have to update it with the new API of the *rest_framework*.